# AWS lambda throw an error occasionally when I invoke the lambda

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, nodejs-server

Lately I have been getting  an error that happens about once a week . maybe it is  related to timeout of lambda or connection to monogoDB but I'm not sure. i using  aws lambda and nodejs14 .

That is the Error:

```
2022-12-19T14:30:40.715Z 2a5e8a43-a315-40e2-a151-97b6630d9d95 ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection {
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "Error: write EPROTO",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "Error",
        "errorMessage": "write EPROTO",
        "code": "EPROTO",
        "errno": -71,
        "syscall": "write",
        "$metadata": {
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        },
        "stack": [
            "Error: write EPROTO",
            "    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: write EPROTO",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)",
        "    at process.emit (domain.js:475:12)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)"
    ]
}
```

The most of time there is no problem when i invoke the lambda .

my function:

```
const repository = new CustomerRepository();
export const getCustomers: any = middlewareBuilder(async (event, _context) => {
    try {
        logger.info('getCustomer start');
        const customers = await repository.findAllCustomers(); // get data from db
        logger.info({ message: ' fetch all customers ', additionalInfo: customers });
        logger.info('getCustomer end  ');
        return httpResult(200, customers);
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('error ' + error);
        throw error;
    }
});
```

I tried to upgrade  nodejs14 to nodejs16.

Comment: without looking at your code, it is a bit challenging to associate the error with the execution flow.

Comment: try using `try catch` and return error while your code throws an error to debug easier

Comment: were you able to resolve it ?